# MySQL thinks that '2015123' is different from '02015123'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zerofill

I am trying yto select a column from my DB where the stockid is equal to the inputted stockid from the user. This is my code below:

```
    $stockid = $_POST['item'];

    //get the current balance of the selected item
    $sqlbal = "SELECT * FROM db.nonperi where nonperi.stockid = '$stockid'";
    $resultbal = $conn-> query($sqlbal);
    if ($resultbal-> num_rows > 0)
    {
        while ($row = $resultbal -> fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $currbal = $row['bal'];
        }
    }
```

I know that the code is correct, however, upon checking in DB, the stockid is equivalent to **'2015123'** but the $stockid that was posted in this page for this code is **'02015123'**. That is why it returns nothing.

Is there any code/way to force sql to see them as the same/equal? I appreciate any help about this.

Comment: Data type for column nonperi.stockid?

Comment: please mention the database structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the stockid as a string (but want it to behave like an integer).
Try

```
$stockid = intval($_POST['item']);
$sqlbal = "SELECT * FROM db.nonperi where nonperi.stockid = $stockid";
```

(That also secures your code to prevent SQL injection)

Comment: So can someone give 2 up-votes for a nice answer with nice to the point explanation?

Comment: Hello Nitek, thanks a lot! This one works perfectly for me and also the solution of habib ul haq below, SOF members really rocks! You guys are genius! Please have me as your apprentice :D

Comment: I think the intval is not necessary on my case since the stockid is posted from a form using a <select> tag and not <input text>, but I still used your sol'n for future purposes :D thanks again.

Comment: For security reasons it is necessary, because people can inject SQL statements into your system otherwise - I'm quite sure you don't want that ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can trim leading 0 (zeros) to check the stockId.

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM '02454545')
```

You command should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM db.nonperi where nonperi.stockid = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM '$stockid')";
```

Comment: Hello Aman Aggarwal, thanks for the comment. This works if all of my data  from DB do not start with '0' but some have '0' on it.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM db.nonperi where nonperi.stockid = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM '$stockid')  or  nonperi.stockid ='$stockid' ";

Comment: @habib ul haq, I haven't thought of that sol'n, your awesome man! Thanks to the both of you!